# "android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am very new to android  can any one  give some detail  that why we use  this permission "android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: The person asking the question needs a sample where this permission is used. Anyone can see the permission list, but a detailed documentation is needed here.

Comment: Did you find the answer for this post? @AbhinavSaxena

Answer (score 0):

This is permission required for System Applications. Commonly we not using this permission. If you are using android studio you can see about this permission. It is one of the protected permission of all permissions. But security applications, such as virus guards, etc, are using this permission.